# cardano-submit-api install error

Tags: cardano-submit-api

I'm trying to install cardano-submit-api on my linux node following IOhk documentation:
cardano-node $ cabal install cardano-submit-api --overwrite-policy=always

but I have an error:
...
Got NamedPackage ouroboros-consensus-cardano-tools
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
error, called at src/Distribution/Client/CmdInstall.hs:474:33 in main:Distribution.Client.CmdInstall

Can anybody help me please? I cannot find any solution :(

Many thanks in advance!
Jaialai

Answer (score 0):

What git tag/branch are you using? Starting with 1.35.4, they moved a lot of compilation to CHaP, but for 1.35.4 tag in particular - the cabal `install` was broken, was fixed on master since. But you should still be able to use build commands for submit-api, and then copy the generated binary to your `$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, yes I'm trying with 1.35.4 version. Finally what I did is take the binary for submit-api directly (compiled for someone who knows more than me :) and it works perfectly. I found it in Armada Alliance Team.

Best regards.